# How to use a reference to a transient variable in Clojure in a thread safe way?

Tags: parsing, clojure

I have a parser function that parses a program from a file and "compiles" it to a list of Clojure functions and a reference to a transient map. The language is a simple DSL with mutable variables (A=A+1). Once compiled, I want to be able to call the list of Clojure functions with some new data and get different values for the mutable variables. Because I use a transient map, to store and change the mutable variables, the code isn't thread-safe. How do I fix this? Is there a way to implement this functionality without transient collections?

In the code below, the file `script` is parsed and generates the `prog` map. The functions are in `:list` and are executed by the `ev` function. I change the `runtime` transient variables between runs.

```
(defn read-script [script]
  (try
    (let [runtime (transient {:vars {:var1 20 :var2 ""}})
          prog    (parse (slurp script) runtime)]
      (run! ev (:list prog)) ; Calls the functions
      (println runtime) ; Show vars
      (assoc! runtime :vars {:var1 78}) ; Initialize vars
      (run! ev (:list prog))
      (println runtime prog) ; Show new vars
      ... )))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was hoping to get a better answer, but this is what I ended up using. My code uses [Vars](https://clojure.org/reference/vars). Vars provide a mechanism to refer to a mutable storage location that can be dynamically rebound (to a new storage location) on a per-thread basis, using [`binding`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/binding). That is the code:

```
(def ^:dynamic runtime ())

(defn run-prog [prog runtime-init]
  (binding [runtime (transient runtime-init)] ;bind the new runtime
    (run! ev (:list prog))  ; Calls the functions
    (persistent! runtime)))

(defn read-script [script]
  (try
    (let [prog (parse (slurp script))]
      (println (run-prog prog {:vars {:var1 20 :var2 ""}}))  ; Show vars
      (println (run-prog prog {:vars {:var1 78}}))  ; Show vars
       ... )))
```

`run-prog` is called with the parsed program (list of function calls) and the initial value for the variables. It returns the final state of the variables and is thread safe (each thread only accesses its own variable map).

If you don't want to use transient collections, you may use [`set!`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/set!) to change the whole variable map to a new value.

Answer (score 4):

The canonical thread-safe, mutable, uncoordinated objects are atoms. Just use atoms instead.

Transients are not only not thread-safe, they must be used *as if* they're actually immutable; for instance: you cannot rely on the side-effect of `assoc!` on a transient map as you do here.

Comment: Atoms do not solve the problem. If the same `prog` is used by two threads at the same time, they will share the `vars` map inside an atom. The reads and writes to the `vars` map will be atomic but both programs will have access to the same variables in the map (and will overwrite each other values).

Comment: @dilvan What do you mean by "but both programs will have access to the same variables in the map (and will overwrite each other values)"? Are different threads never allowed to manipulate the same values in the map?

Comment: Correct, each thread should have its own variables. Each should have its own `vars` map.

Comment: @dilvan Couldn't you just have an atom of nested maps that are keyed by thread id or some other thread-specific identifier? Something like `(atom {1 {:some-var 30}, 2 {:some-var 32}})`.

Comment: @dilvan if that's what you want, rewrite the program to explicitly take the `runtime` as an argument. that way you can provide a separate runtime for each thread if you need to.